# Need to convert Java AES/CBC/PKCS5 Padding Encryption and decryption to dart code-Flutter

Tags: java, flutter, aes

I need to convert java code for encryption and decryption using AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding algorithm to dart code.

The java code of AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding encryption and decryption:

```
package test_Terminal.classes;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

/**
 *
 * @author jeena
 */
public class IOTEncodingDecoding {

    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec;
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec;
    String EncryptionKey = "733D3A17-D8A0-454B-AD22-88608FD0C46A";
    String saltString = "FA9A4D0F-5523-4EEF-B226-9A3E8F14FEF8";
    String algorithm = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    int encoding_mode;

    test_Terminal.classes.general General = new test_Terminal.classes.general();

    void setSecretKey() {
        try {
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(EncryptionKey.toCharArray(), saltString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE), 1000, 384);
            byte[] derivedData = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec).getEncoded();

            byte[] key = new byte[32];
            byte[] iv = new byte[16];

            System.arraycopy(derivedData, 0, key, 0, key.length);
            System.arraycopy(derivedData, key.length, iv, 0, iv.length);

            secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            General.LogException("setSecretKey", e);
        }
    }

    public String encrypt(String input) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivSpec);
            byte[] cipherText ;
            if(encoding_mode==1)            
                cipherText = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE));
            else
                cipherText = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());                            
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            General.LogException("encrypt", e);
        }
        return "";
    }

    public String decrypt(String cipherText) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivSpec);
            byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText));
            if(encoding_mode==1)
                return new String(plainText, StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE);
            else
                return new String(plainText);
            
                
        } catch (Exception e) {
            General.LogException("decrypt", e);
            General.LogActivity("decrypt", e.getMessage());
        }
        return "Ticket format error";
    }

    public void setMode() {              
        setSecretKey();                         
    }

}
```

I need to get the following result:

Input(PlainText):C123492349C1CT20230206130645.
Output(Encrypted string):8tyHRaQCsxmmGW2xPBFYx/PALmvHkmjx/TzaXC2rIv0=

This is the dart code that I've got so far for decryption, but I'm getting error.

```
 Uint8List? decrypt(String ciphertext, String password) {
    Uint8List rawCipher = base64.decode(ciphertext);
    var salt = rawCipher.sublist(0, 0 + 8);
    var iv = rawCipher.sublist(8, 8 + 16);
    var encrypted = rawCipher.sublist(8 + 16);

    Uint8List key = generateKey(password, salt);
    print('key => $key');
    CBCBlockCipher cipher = CBCBlockCipher(AESEngine());

    ParametersWithIV<KeyParameter> params =
        ParametersWithIV<KeyParameter>(KeyParameter(key), iv);
    PaddedBlockCipherParameters<ParametersWithIV<KeyParameter>, Null>
        paddingParams =
        PaddedBlockCipherParameters<ParametersWithIV<KeyParameter>, Null>(
            params, null);
    PaddedBlockCipherImpl paddingCipher =
        PaddedBlockCipherImpl(PKCS7Padding(), cipher);
    paddingCipher.init(false, paddingParams);

    var val = paddingCipher.process(encrypted);

    String res = String.fromCharCodes(val);

    debugPrint('res => $res');

    return val;
  }

 Uint8List generateKey(String passphrase, Uint8List salt) {
    final derivator = PBKDF2KeyDerivator(HMac(SHA1Digest(), 64))
      ..init(Pbkdf2Parameters(salt, 1024, 16));
    return derivator.process(utf8.encode(passphrase) as Uint8List);
  }
```

[I got this code from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72945189/converting-aes-decryption-function-from-java-to-flutter)

The Exception that I'm getting is:

```
Exception has occurred.
ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s): Input data length must be a multiple of cipher's block size)
```

I think the values inside rawCipher.sublist() function is wrong. I'm stuck on this problem for few days, please help.

Comment: Can you tell which package you are using in dart? It will easy to debug.

Comment: pointycastle: ^3.6.2, this is the package I've used.

Answer (score 0):

Both codes differ:

- Regarding encodings: The Dart code does not consider the UTF-16 LE encoding of the salt. Furthermore, the encoding of the plaintext is unclear. For `encoding_mode==1` it is UTF-16LE, otherwise it corresponds to the platform encoding in your environment (which only you know).
- Regarding PBKDF2: The Java code derives key and IV from a static salt (note that a static salt is a vulnerability), while the Dart code assumes a concatenation in the order `salt|IV|ciphertext` during encryption (using a random 8 bytes salt and a random IV).
  Also, different iteration counts are used: 1000 in the Java code, 1024 in the Dart code (note that both values are generally much too small for PBKDF2).

The differences can be fixed as follows:

- Regarding encodings: In the Dart code, the salt must first be UTF-16 LE encoded: Since the [*utf* package](https://pub.dev/packages/utf) is deprecated, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68090107/9014097) for a UTF-16 LE encoding and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67802971/9014097) for the decoding. The encoding can be adapted to:

  ```dart
  Uint8List encodeUtf16LE(String salt) {
    var byteData = ByteData(salt.codeUnits.length * 2);
    for (var i = 0; i < salt.codeUnits.length; i += 1) {
      byteData.setUint16(i * 2, salt.codeUnits[i], Endian.little);
    }
    return byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
  }
  ```

  Moreover, from the sample data it can be concluded (by testing) that the plaintext in the Java code has been encoded with UTF-8.
- Regarding PBKDF2: In the Dart code, key and IV must be derived from the static salt applied in the Java code.
  Also, the parameters from the Java code must be applied (digest: SHA-1, iteration count: 1000, keysize: 32 + 16 = 48 bytes):

  ```dart
  Uint8List generateKey(String passphrase, Uint8List salt) {
    final derivator = PBKDF2KeyDerivator(HMac(SHA1Digest(), 64))
      ..init(Pbkdf2Parameters(salt, 1000, 32 + 16));
    return derivator.process(utf8.encode(passphrase) as Uint8List);
  }
  ```

With these changes, key and IV can be derived as follows:

```dart
var salt = "FA9A4D0F-5523-4EEF-B226-9A3E8F14FEF8";
var passphrase = "733D3A17-D8A0-454B-AD22-88608FD0C46A";
var saltBytes = encodeUtf16LE(salt);
var keyIv = generateKey(passphrase, saltBytes);
var key = keyIv.sublist(0, 32);
var iv = keyIv.sublist(32, 32 + 16);
```

The decryption code can be applied unchanged, for decoding use `utf8.decode()` instead of `String.fromCharCodes()`.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:pointycastle/export.dart';
...
var ciphertext = "8tyHRaQCsxmmGW2xPBFYx/PALmvHkmjx/TzaXC2rIv0=";
var encrypted = base64.decode(ciphertext);
var paddingCipher = PaddedBlockCipherImpl(PKCS7Padding(), CBCBlockCipher(AESEngine()))
  ..init(false, PaddedBlockCipherParameters(ParametersWithIV(KeyParameter(key), iv), null));
var decryptedBytes = paddingCipher.process(encrypted);
var decrypted = utf8.decode(decryptedBytes); // C123492349C1CT20230206130645
```

Comment: Could you please share how to do encryption also, I tried it with the code for decryption but I'm getting errors.

Comment: @Malavikaks - The key/IV derivation is the same for encryption and decryption. So you only need to replace the decryption part (i.e. the last code snippet) with the encryption part, which requires only minimal changes. Post your code and describe the problem. If the post becomes too long, you can also post a new question.